# How do I set Host Groups on Fail2ban for Wordpress?

Tags: regex, fail2ban, filter

I'm trying to set up a custom filter for fail2ban on a wordpress site. I've been following [this tutorial](https://1fix.io/blog/2015/01/10/wordpress-brute-force-attacks-fail2ban/) but when I try to test my custom filter, I get the error: server.failregex.RegexException: No 'host' group in '/etc/...

I've been researching this problem and I see that filters are supposed to be wrapped in (?P ... ) as per [the documentation](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Filters)

So my file looks like this:

```
# Fail2Ban filter for Wordpress
#

# WP brute force attacks filter
[Definition]
failregex = (?P<host> ^ .* "POST )  /wp-login.php
ignoreregex =
```

I've tried different permutations of placing the (?P ... ) around different parts of the regex but after looking around, I'm honestly not sure what the correct syntax is. Can someone explain the syntax to me so that I can get this up and running?

I'm not sure if these details matter but, my server is running Apache/PHP and has cloudflare running on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Test your regex with the cli tool `fail2ban-regex`.